# Unexpected token at @ error in Aurelia module

Tags: babeljs, aurelia

When I run an Aurelia app, I get the following error in Chrome. I get the error wherever I have **@**. For example, `@customElement` and `@bindable` gives the error.

[image]

My config.js looks like below:

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/",
  "transpiler": "babel",
  "babelOptions": {
    "optional": [
      "runtime"
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "*": "*.js",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*.js",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*.js"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@customElement` and `@bindable` are called [decorators](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators) which is an experimental feature in JavaScript ES7, so it is currently not supported by the browsers.

However babel can also transpile this feature back to ES5 which is then can be executed by the common browsers

You just need to configure this feature in babel with using the `es7.decorators` [option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/):

```
  "babelOptions": {
    "optional": [
      "es7.decorators",
      "runtime"
    ]
  },
```

You can always check the [Aurelia navigation skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) as a reference for the [config.js](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/config.js) or other setup options.